# Why won't a @Html.ActionLink render inside an li tag?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, actionlink

My question is simple. I have an unordered list `<ul>... </ul>` with a bunch of `<li>...</li>` tags. Inside those `<li>` tags I have some `@Html.ActionLink(...)` that just won't render. Am I doing something fundimentally wrong here? This is my code:

```
<div id="menuDiv">
    <ul id="myMenu">
        <li >@Html.ActionLink("Dashboard", "Index", new { sender = "AgentScoreCareReport"})</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: So you have a route defined as `[HttpGet]Index(string sender)`?

Comment: It renders. even the exact code mentioned by you works for me.

Comment: It works for me too, maybe there is something wrong with your CSS class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<li >@Html.ActionLink("Dashboard", "Index", 
    new { sender = "AgentScoreCareReport"},null)</li>
```

Comment: I tried that too. It just won't render. Is there an issue with rendering HTML helpers inside of old style HTML tags (such as <li> tags)?

Comment: The fact that it works for some of you makes me think that it's something fundamental I'm missing. Any thoughts?

Comment: I just tried it on another MVC project and it worked?! Go figure.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a CSS problem. It's been fixed.

Thanks everyone who made suggestions!